# How to match column partially contained in another column?

Tags: sql, string, db2

I have two columns such as:

```
col1      col2
----      ----
5qt       exception for 5qt ammended
5qt       exception for 5076 ammended
6d3       6d3 registered
```

I want to string match so that if the value of `col1` exists in `col2`, return col2.

So I get:

```
exception for 5qt ammended
6d3 registered
```

I have tried using `locate()` but not with much luck:

```
select col2 from mytable
where locate(col1,col2) = 1;
```

I have previously had this working where `col2` began with the value of `col1` i.e.

```
col1        col2
----        ----
5qt         5qt ammended
5qt         5076 ammended
6d3         6d3 registered
```

But it seems the fact the value of `col1` can appear in any position of `col2` is throwing `locate()` off the trail.

Comment: Result set shown for "previously had this working" contradicts "col2 began with the value of col1"; i.e. pending any edit\correction since ~2hrs after initially posting.
FWiW the predicate `position(col1 in col2)>0` as an effective equivalent of the already-offered `locate(col1,col2)>=1` might, to some, seem more conspicuous for the intended effect.  Also FWiW, without DDL, some offers of advice may be incompatible with the actual requirements, per having made false assumptions about what is the actual DDL; e.g. RTRIM could be apropos for use with the LIKE predicate, for CHAR vs VARCHAR

Comment: It wasn't a result set, but an MWE of what my attempt does work on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your logic is okay.  Just fix the comparison:

```
select col2
from mytable
where locate(col1, col2) >= 1;
```

Alternatively, you can use `like`:

```
where col2 like '%' || col1 || '%'
```

Comment: Hi Gordon thanks - that only problem is that susbtrings of `col1` seem to satisfy the search criteria in `col2`. on values in `col2` that contain the entire value of `col` must be allowed.

unfortunately I am unable to test your second suggestion - due to a permissions issue.

Comment: @Gordon is right - as the LOCATE function returns the starting position  - are you sure you have changed your "=" to ">=" as he suggested?

Answer (score 1):

Solutions of Gordon work, you can use too:

```
where position(col1  in col2 ) > 0
```

or use:

```
where replace(col2 ,col1 , '') <> col2
```